# Vue.js keep-alive doesn't work

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

What exactly happened to vue.js keep-alive feature for caching components? [This pen](https://codepen.io/sdras/pen/db71c231f760ee3a53e9d4e65f8745b8) work with [2.0.1](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.1/vue.min.js), but doesn't works with [current vue.js version](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue).

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="container">
    <main>
      <keep-alive>
        <component :is="selected">
        ...
        </component>
      </keep-alive>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

p.s. the `activated` & `deactivated` events are fired.

Comment: Hi there - can you clarify what you're trying to do with the various components that you bind your component to (i.e. the different values for `selected`. The objects you define in `components` are not really component objects as they only have template properties. Check out this doc for more on how to register components: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html

Comment: I recommend using Vue 3. It should work just fine with the latest version. You’ll also have less problems if you run Vue locally on your machine in an IDE such as VS Code. As you can see from the official documentation, keep-alive is still a feature: https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/keep-alive.html

Comment: Not really sure what you want to achieve, but look at https://jsfiddle.net/nahev1yf/